# how does code that interacts with model get attached to req.user

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I just came across the following line of code in a routes file that uses express.js

```
req.user.getCompany({
    scope : ['with_active_users', 'order_by_active_users'],
  })
```

The line of code in question can be found [HERE](https://github.com/timeoff-management/timeoff-management-application/blob/master/lib/route/departments.js#L90).

My guess is this line of code is interactive with a Model but i'am not sure. Also where exactly is getCompany being attached to the `user` object ? I can't understand that.

Answer (score 2):

The `req.user` was a functionality provided by the `passportjs` library: [After a user logs in successfully, passport will attach a "user" object onto `req.user`](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/)

The exact configuration of what exactly will be in the `req.user` object, and how to authenticate/find the user through database is implemented by the developer, as seen in the [/passport/index.js file](https://github.com/timeoff-management/timeoff-management-application/blob/master/lib/passport/index.js) - specifically the `strategy_handler` function